# How to modify the filter on datagrid based on the current scope in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, datagrid, module

This is one of my many filters:

```
 filter(:item_id, :enum,
         :header => "Category",
         :select => lambda { scope.select(" distinct(category.title), transactions.item_id ").map {|p| [p.title, p.item_id]}},
         :multiple => false,
         :include_blank => true
  ) do |value|
      self.where(:items => { :id => value } )
  end
```

As you can see it is calling the Category from the DB (All of them)

In my report in the SalesReportController I have this:

```
  def index
    user_acls = find_current_user_acls
    @grid = SalesReportsGrid.new(params[:sales_reports_grid]) do |scope|
      scope.where("access_lists.id" => user_acls).page(params[:page])
    end
    @grid.assets

  end
```

This will give me the scope which generate the Grid and passes to the view.

Now I need to make the filter to show only the sold categories by this user.

All I need to do is somehow passing the `user_acls` to the `SalesReportsGrid` Class

If I can pass the `user_acls` then I can do this:

```
 filter(:item_id, :enum,
         :header => "Category",
         :select => lambda { scope.select(" distinct(category.title), transactions.item_id ").where("access_lists.id" => user_acls).map {|p| [p.title, p.item_id]}},
         :multiple => false,
         :include_blank => true
  ) do |value|
      self.where(:items => { :id => value } )
  end
```

**A Quick explanation:**

For example:

User1 is an agent
She sold 100 items from 4 categories.
She goes to the report page.
At the moment based on the above code I show her only her own sold items however the filter dropdown consists of all of the categories in the DB which it doesn't make sense to have.

Unfortunately my ACL module is a bit granular and when I try to extend it in the `SalesReportsGrid` (`sales_reports_grid.rb`) I get undefined error for some of the methods. it is because my Authentication module has lots of other methods from other modules like Devise and Declarative Authorization. So I don't think extend will be an option here.
Thanks in advance

Edit:

in the controller:

```
def index
   # This will return an array of ACL ids for the user
  user_acls = find_current_user_acls 

  @grid = SalesReportsGrid.new(params[:sales_reports_grid].merge(user_acls: user_acls)) do |scope|
      scope.where("access_lists.id" => user_acls).page(params[:page])
  end
  @grid.assets
end
```

beside the error I get about: `undefined method merge for nil:NilClass`

`params[:sales_reports_grid]` has nothing in it that is why I get the error.

when I use this `SalesReportsGrid.new(user_acls: user_acls )` on its own, I get the result.

I guess this is the limit of my ActiveRecord :(

I have added this in the SalesGrid `attr_accessor :user_acls`

Thanks

**All worked mate:**

Can you please explain this bit as I cant understand it: 
When I added this:
`:select => lambda { scope.select(" distinct(categories.title), transactions.item_id ").where("access_lists.id" => :user_acls).map {|p| [p.title, p.item_id]} }`

`:user_acls` value never returned however when I do this:

```
 def categories_select
    scope.select(" distinct(category.title), transactions.item_id ").where("access_lists.id" => user_acls).map {|p| [p.title, p.item_id]}

  end
```

and add the `:select => :categories_select` all works fine.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass whatever object to Datagrid object.

For example current_user, ALC object or accessible categories.

So in your case solution would look like:

```
class SalesReportsGrid
  scope { ... }

  attr_accessor :user_ucls

  filter(:item_id, :enum, select: :categories_select, ...) do
    ...
  end


  def categories_select
    scope.select(" distinct(category.title), transactions.item_id ").where("access_lists.id" => user_acls).map {|p| [p.title, p.item_id]}
  end

end

SalesReportsGrid.new(params.fetch(:sales_reports_grid, {}).merge(user_acls: user_acls))
```

Note that in order to access grid object data from `select` option you need to extract it to a method.

The error you mentioned is spawned from the Nil class limitation: `nil.merge({})`.
In order to avoid that, add the default value to Hash using the `fetch` method like in example above.

Comment: do I need to put `SalesGrid.new(current_user: User.first)` in the controller? I did it and I get undefined method error. Or I am missing something? Does it need to go in the index action? I have already defined the SalesGrid.new in the index with the page params.

Comment: `SalesGrid` should respond to `#current_user=` method. You can define it as part of a filter as an example above or use `attr_accessor :current_user`.

Comment: Can you please read the end of my question. Thanks for your help mate. Cheers